# Subquery error calculating Free throw statistics

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

trying to incorporate the query titled "free throws made" as a subquery into the query below it titled "FreeThrowPercByGame" but getting an error.  Both work independent of each other in Google Big Query. Thank you.

```
--free throws made
  select  scheduled_date,
        home_market,
    away_market,
    team_name,
    count( *)FreeThrowMade,
    FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_pbp_sr` gamestbl
    WHERE season IN (2017)
    AND (home_market IN ("Ohio State")
      OR away_market IN ("Ohio State"))
    AND event_type IN ("freethrowmade")
    AND period in (1,2)
    AND team_name IN ("Buckeyes")
    group by 
    scheduled_date,
        home_market,
    away_market,
    team_name
      ORDER BY
    scheduled_date asc


--FreeThrowPercByGame
    select
    scheduled_date,
    home_market,
    away_market,
    team_name,
    count(event_type IN ("freethrowmiss","freethrowmade"))NoOfFTAttempts
    FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_pbp_sr` gamestbl
    WHERE
    season IN (2017)
    AND (home_market IN ("Ohio State")
      OR away_market IN ("Ohio State"))
    AND event_type IN ("freethrowmiss","freethrowmade")
    AND period in (1,2)
    AND team_name IN ("Buckeyes")
    group by 
    scheduled_date,
        home_market,
    away_market,
    team_name
      ORDER BY
    scheduled_date asc
```

Comment: you should post the error aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is simple combining of your already working queries into one (working one)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  scheduled_date,
  home_market,
  away_market,
  team_name,
  COUNTIF(event_type = 'freethrowmade') FreeThrowMade,
  COUNT(1) NoOfFTAttempts
FROM `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_pbp_sr` gamestbl
WHERE season IN (2017)
AND (
  home_market IN ("Ohio State")
  OR away_market IN ("Ohio State")
  )
AND event_type IN ("freethrowmiss","freethrowmade")
AND period IN (1,2)
GROUP BY 
  scheduled_date,
  home_market,
  away_market,
  team_name
ORDER BY scheduled_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them combined, consider something like the following:

```
with data as (
  select scheduled_date,home_market,away_market,team_name,
         count(distinct case when event_type in('freethrowmiss','freethrowmade') then event_id else null end) as attempts, 
         count(distinct case when event_type in('freethrowmade') then event_id else null end) as makes
  from `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_pbp_sr`
  where season = 2017 and period in(1,2) AND (home_market = "Ohio State" or away_market = 'Ohio State') and team_name = 'Buckeyes'
  group by 1,2,3,4
)
select *, safe_divide(makes,attempts) as freethrowpercentage
from data
order by 1 asc
```

Comment: great , thanks i need to read up on 'distinct case' and I'm new to that "with" statement

Comment: The reason I chose to use `count(distinct case)` in my query is only to make sure there are not duplicate events.  The other submitted answers would not catch these errors (if they exist). They are not wrong, I am just in the habit of not trusting data.  I like the use of CTEs, i think they make code more readable.  If you were sharing this code with coworkers, i think the other answers calculations for freethrowpercentage are a little less clear as they still have the formulas, whereas mine is clearly `makes` divided by `attempts` (although wrapped in a `safe` to catch errors).

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want conditional aggregation, which is particularly simple using `countif()`:

```
select scheduled_date, home_market, away_market, team_name,
       countif(event_type in ('freethrowmade')) / nullif(countif(event_type in ('freethrowmade', 'freethrowmiss')), 0) as ratio
from `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_pbp_sr` gamestbl
where season in (2017) and
      'Ohio State' in (home_market, away_market) and
      period in (1,2) and
      team_name in ('Buckeyes')
group scheduled_date, home_market, away_market, team_name
order by scheduled_date asc
```